# Can someone identify what is wrong in my palindrome detector?

Tags: java

```
String input;
int longestpali = 0;
String original, reverse = "";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
input = sc.next();

for(int j = 0; j < input.length(); j = j + 1)

    for(int k = 0; k < input.length(); k = k + 1) {

        original = input.substring(j,k);

        int length = original.length();

        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

        if (original.equals(reverse))
            longestpali = original.length();
    }

System.out.println(longestpali);
```

it says there is an error at `original = input.substring(j,k);`
This code is suppose to search throughout the whole input to find the longest palindrome.

Comment: In the future, please make sure you give all relevant information. Saying "there is an error" without saying which one is like going to the doctor with "I hurt somewhere".

Answer (score 0):

You could take the value of each string with the "YOURSTRINGHERE.length" method, and take the amount of characters in the string. You could then compare those value against each other with a couple of if loops, and do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `k` needs to start from `i`, not from `0`, otherwise you end up doing `.substring(1, 0)`, with end before the start; this will raise `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thanks XD I should of saw that myself earlier, my bad

Answer (score 0):

This should be your first inner loop

for(int k = j+1; k < imput.length(); k = k + 1){
..
}

Comment: And also Its better use StringBuilder instead of String, where you have reverse in built function which you can use instead of using loops like this.